# Expect and Allow are not stubbing Singleton methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have an Utils class that looks something like this

```
module A
  class Utils
    class << self
      def foo(arg)
        return arg
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And I'm trying to stub the `foo` method but both `allow` and `expect` don't work and the method is called either way, what am I doing wrong on my spec?

I tried stubbing by doing

```
allow(A::Utils).to receive(:foo).and_return("test")
expect(A::Utils).to receive(:foo).and_return("test")
```

Comment: why do you think it doesn't work? You can write a test with the exact example code from your question, and it'll pass:

`specify "RSpec stubs singleton class methods" do
      module A
        class Utils
          class << self
            def foo(arg)
              return arg
            end
          end
        end
      end
      allow(A::Utils).to receive(:foo).and_return("test")
      expect(A::Utils.foo("test")).to eq("test")
end`

Comment: What means "don't work" ? maybe you can provide some test cases to clarify your question ...